# Do I need to give attribution if I use Stack Overflow for learning new things?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, attribution

Suppose I a find solution to my problem on Stack Overflow. Do I need to give attribution to the particular question that helped me? The license at the bottom says "you need to give attribution", but I do not understand why give attribution to common programming things.

If I write java programs and use tips and suggestions from Stack Overflow, do I have cite Stack Overflow each time?

I do not have websites and I use Stack Overflow for programming and learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you **copy** the text of a post (question or answer, in part or whole) and put it somewhere public on the web (say, your own blog), you need to attribute it.

That means you should link to it and say where that text came from and who it came from.

Comment: what if i do not post them on the web but use them for personal learning or creating programs?

Comment: @Programmer - up to you, in particular if no one else will see them. But consider that for learning - you may want to know where a piece of code came from.

Comment: yes. So that means i only have to attribute when i copy the data and put it on the web, not when i just use their ideas to research myself and create my own programs myself?

Comment: @Programmer - think about attribution in the same way that scientific writing attributes data, ideas and information to other writers. If anyone is going to be seeing it, you should be attributing it. I am saying that if you are the only one who sees it, no one can check on you.

Comment: if i create an app with some research from stack overflow (not copying exact code but using some techniques) and other people uses my app, then do i need to attribute ?

Comment: Techniques don't need attributions. Stuff other people wrote does, @Programmer

Comment: Now I got it. So I cannot copy other people's code but i can use their ideas and techniques freely in my program, and if i do copy their exact code, i have to attribute the user whose code i copied, isnt it ?

Comment: @Programmer - that's pretty much it. Though this extends to the text of the post if you use it as is.

Comment: "Though this extends to the text of the post if you use it as is" - sorry sir, but what does this line mean (my english is not good) @Oded

Comment: @Programmer - most people write stuff that is not just code. So the other stuff they write. Like this comment. Or the text that **explains** the code.

Comment: oh I see. When in problem, I just require stuffs like- how to do this/that, which class to use, which method to use, what is the best way to do this/that etc. Thank you very much for your help.